# SQL - Grabbing only a portion of the message in a each row

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a column name "value" in table T with a long description of errors, it has here is an example of few

but it is also grabbing other rows which i don't need.

Please help?

Answer (score 2):

This answers the original version of the question.

To filter the rows, use `regexp_like()`.  I would suggest:

```
select t.*
from t
where regexp_like(value, '^An image has error at (1203|12345):')
```

I am guessing that the final colon is important for the matching.

Comment: To use this regexp_like(value, '^An image has error at (1203|12345):')
the end numbers will be different on each row. they are error numbers and they vary.

Comment: @user2830993 . . . This answers the original version of the question.  You changed the question, as if to invalidate the answers of people who were trying to help answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use the `LIKE` operator?

```sql
SELECT t.id, t.value, SUBSTR(t.value, 1, INSTR(t.value, ':')) short_value
  FROM t
 WHERE value LIKE 'An image has error at 1203:%'
    OR value LIKE 'An image has error at 12345:%';
```

Comment: When using `UPPER(value)`, the compared string should be in upper case ('AN IMAGE HAS ...').

Comment: Thank you! I will try this!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your best option seems is a combination of a standard substr+instr to extract the desired value with a regexp_like to determine overall string t desirability overall string.

```
select substr(value, 1, instr(value, ':')-1 ) value
  from d 
 where regexp_like (value,'An image has error at \d+:');
```

Although depending the exact requirement for leading test requirement and following numeric value perhaps just

```
select substr(value, 1, instr(value, ':')-1 ) value
  from d 
 where instr(value, ':') > 1;
```

Finally you can stay with [regexp_substr](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303) if you wish. However, Oracle's syntax for that is totally counter intuitive to use of regular expressions:

```
select value
  from (select regexp_substr(value, '(.*):', 1, 1, 'i', 1) value
          from d
       )
 where value is not null;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=de52a02bbd018607fff3003bc524d541)

Comment: Thanks! I will try